# murder integrate with capistrano

Tags: capistrano

when I integrate with murder in capistrano v3.2.1,I add "require 'murder'" in Capfile,and input command "cap production deploy ",then It output the error below:

```
root@ubuntu:~/deploy# cap production deploy --trace
cap aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `instance' for Capistrano::Configuration:Class
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/murder-0.1.2/lib/murder.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
/root/deploy/Capfile:7:in `<top (required)>',
```

give some details or advice to me,thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's because murder is for capistrano 2, not capistrano 3